# How to read the .setting file?

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

May i know how to check the connectionstring from the .setting file when my apps load? I want to make my apps to read connectionstring from .setting file instead from the app.config.
Then if there is no connectionstring in .setting file, then i should display a dialog to enter the server name and runtime write to the .setting file.

How do i achieve the function above for my clickonce deployment which targetting multiple computers. Could you advice?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use the following to read, assuming you have a setting called ConnectString

```
string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectString;
```

To be able to write back to the .setting you also need to ensure you set it as a user "scope" setting varible and then simply set the property

```
Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectString = "new connection string";
```

and to persist the change use

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

You could read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi i wonder whether i can do this. If i have 10 clients from different computers using a same set of code and if i know their computer server name, can i just pump in 10 set of different connectionstring in the .setting file? then when the app load in client pc, it will read the "Name" of the connectionstring which match their server name and get that. is this a correct statement?

Comment: all the "NAME" will be the same. only the "Value" for connectionstring are different. is this correct?

Comment: yes I don't see why you couldn't do that, having different connect string to match each server that is.

Comment: I am using linqtosql. i failed to write the `properties.setting` at the datamodel layer. It seems that it allows me to write that only in the startup project which same layer with .setting file. I need to write that at datamodel layer as i am calling the datacontext from there

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting;](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397759.aspx) to read from settings.

Comment: i am not able to write Properties.Settings.. did i miss any reference?

Comment: Like mvandersteen mentioned you need to change scope(see scoup column in settings) to user to write setting

Comment: sorry i meant i failed to write this code. Properties.. there is no properties found.

Comment: Go to you project properties, click on settings tab if you see "This project does not contain a default settings file" click on that link. After that you will be able to find Settings in Properties namespace.

Comment: I can add connectionstring in that setting file. But isn't it i have to write this in code behind?   string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectString; from my apps to call the connectionstring from that setting file? .. there i failed to write the Properties ..